# Visual C++ 2017, extern "C" ignored? LNK2019 errors when linking C++ code to C libraries

Tags: c, visual-studio-2017, linker-errors

A solution has a project consisting of a static library (one .h file, one .c file) written in C, and a utility program (.cxx) based on that library written in C++.

The library compiles without error.  The utility compiles too, but fails in linkage with errors like:

```
1>abc.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "struct DEFListen * __cdecl DEFisten(int,char *,int)" (?DEFListen@@YAPAU0@HPADH@Z) referenced in function _main
```

The header for the library includes extern "C" guards:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
```

By putting garbage inside the ifdef, I get compile warnings when compiling (not linking) the utility as expected, so I know __cplusplus is in fact defined when the utility is compiled, and not for instance merely misspelled.

Yet, the error message shows the function signature (and the mangled name) for the function in question.  `dumbin /symbols` on the utility's object file of course confirms the object contains mangled symbols.

In summary: `extern "C" {` is definitely being parsed at compile time yet ignored.  Why?

Comment: Suggest you try to create an actual miaimal example that exhibits the problem rather than just telling us things you (think you) know :-) Often that process makes it obvious *why* you're having a problem.

Comment: Just tested it locally and it works as expected. We use C libraries for a lot of things so I didn't expect it wouldn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is so stupid: is that the closing brace code (below) had been cut and pasted to an alternate location, while re-arranging declarations, leaving several functions outside the extern block.

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

Sorry I didn't spot that before posting for help.

I leave this shameful post to found by someone equally foolish (possibly me) in the future.